# How do I create a list with a command using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot that is going to make 2 teams out of a list that the user created with one command. I just don't know how to create a list out of the elements that the user inputs. I want the user to write for example `!team a b c d e f` which should create a list that looks like this: `list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]`. I want the command that the user inputs in discord to start with `!team`, and after that the user is going to write all of the list elements.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)?

Comment: There are a few ways to register or manually parse commands (the `!team` part) and I won't go in to that as it depends if you're deriving from client or bot and even then you have options, but splitting the list up is straightforward. For example, `my_list = 'a b c d'.split()` will set `my_list` to be `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
    items = message.content.split()
    print(items)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. However, it includes !team in the list. What should I do to make it not get included?

Comment: I was doing some experimenting myself, and I found out that I can just pop the first item of the list.

Comment: i would use `items = message.content.split()[1:]`.

`.pop()` will fail if the message content was somehow empty. It won't happen realistically, but if the library has a bug it could maybe happen. `[1:]` will never fail

Answer (score 1):

First, you might want to use a [command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=args#command) rather than an `on_message` event like another user had suggested. To get a list from a command, you can use `*args`. You can view more about [variables in commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#variable) in the discord.py docs. `*args`, when used, would return a list such as `('a', 'b', 'c')` depending on the given input. Do view the example below.

```py
@client.command() # or @bot.command() depending on what you're using
async def team(ctx, *args): # command would be run as !team a b c d e
    print(args) # printing how the list would look like
    await ctx.send(', '.join(args)) # makes it look neater rather than sending a normal list
```

Here is how the above command would look.

[image: The command above working]

Answer (score 0):

If you use commands instead on the `on_messags` event this will be easier:

```py
@bot.command(name='listcommands')
async def list_commands(ctx, *message):
    List = message.split()
    await ctx.send(response)
```

But you could do this with an `on_message` event:

```py
@client.event
asynce def on_message(message):
    If (message.author == client.user)
           return

    If message.content.startswith('$commands')
            List = message.content.split('$commands ', 1)
```

Comment: I think you meant
`_, words = message.content.split('$commands ', 1); lst = words.split()`